# cannot install sample data with the installation of opensis

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

Currently I'm trying to install opensis but the installation FAILED in step 3 after choosing to

```
**install sample data**
```

the installation continue normally if you choose **not** to install sample data
any "Other Configuration" should be done.

Working on XAMPP, MySQL, PHP 5.5.24, Windows 7

Thanks

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking

Comment: I am trying to install OpenSIS in my Laptop and I failed in step 3 when I  tried to install sample data